# Wordpress theme hidding header email on mobile screens

Tags: css, wordpress, hide, show-hide, hidden-field

My site is the following:

http://www.evarancho.com/

The problem is that the email on the header is hiding when you make the screen smaller. I don´t know how because it was not happen before and it just started out of nowhere.

I have tried this css line but it is not working.

```
.w-text-h{display:show !important;}
```

I don´t know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems the whole div <div class="w-text ush_text_3"> is removed from the DOM when you resize, so I think it is removed with JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I see it on the screen in mobile.

Anyways, `display: show` is not right.

Try `display: block !important`

Comment: That is not working for me. I see the email for a second and then it disappears and the language flag goes to the left. 
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to narrow down.

I suspect this is the issue:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
.header_hor .l-subheader.at_top {line-height:36px;height:36px;}
**.header_hor .l-header.*sticky* .l-subheader.at_top {*line-height:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;*}**
.header_hor .l-subheader.at_middle {line-height:50px;height:50px;}
.header_hor .l-header.sticky .l-subheader.at_middle {line-height:50px;height:50px;}
.l-subheader.at_bottom { display:none; }
.header_hor .l-subheader.at_bottom {line-height:50px;height:50px;}
.header_hor .l-header.sticky .l-subheader.at_bottom {line-height:50px;height:50px;}
```

The line height 0 and all all that would definitely be a problem and I believe it is set to sticky (in the us.headerSettings javascript source on the page, the header is set to sticky). A possible quick fix, rather than editing the CSS (suggested process mentioned below), might be to make the header not sticky in the settings. Though I'm not familiar with this theme, so I can't be sure that that will fix it, but it's a good bet.

If not the above, this might be the next place to look:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
.ush_text_3 { font-size:13px; }
}

.ush_text_3 { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Perhaps the nowrap is causing an issue? I'd see what happens if it's removed.

These changes can be made in the css style file directly with to issues: 1. if you break it it's not easily recovered and 2. you'll lose changes with theme update.
Usually, making a child theme and adding the custom changes in the child themes style is recommended.

This can be done with one of many wordpress child theme plugins. I recommend [Child Theme Configurator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/)

There's also an error with the color in the css file, but it isn't the issue as it's just ignored:

```
.ush_text_3 .w-text-value { color:; }
```

(see errors [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evarancho.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fus-assets%2FImpreza-theme-options.css%3Fver%3D3.2.1&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).)

Comment: The CSS does not seem like working. I still see the email and then it disappears in a second. I can´t edit the header setting because of a problem with the old owner and the theme licence.